# Unable to access my Spring Boot application from browser

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class TrackingManagementSystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TrackingManagementSystemApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I ran the above application by using **mvn spring-boot:run** command it is deploying successfully but when i am trying to access it from browser it is throwing Http 404 exception.
I wanna access it from any web browser.

thank you

Comment: What is in the address field of your browser?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/track-service/

Comment: Try using localhost:8080/hello instead.

Comment: application.properties           server.port=8080
server.context-path=/track-service
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.basedir=target/tomcat
security.basic.enabled=false

Comment: This localhost page can’t be found

No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/hello
Search Google for localhost 8080 hello
HTTP ERROR 404 was the result

Comment: localhost:8080/track-service/hello should work.

Comment: yes its working.... thanks dunni......